Reference Request: Continuous extension of conformal maps
currently I am trying to find some references on the continuous extension of conformal maps between two simply connected domains of the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb C}$. Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ be two simple bounded curves on the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb C}$ and let $f \colon \hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \gamma_1 \to \hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \gamma_2$ be a conformal map between two simply connected domains.
Question: Under what conditions does $f$ extend continuously (not necessarily injectively) on the boundary $\gamma_1$ in terms of prime ends of $\hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \gamma_1$. Most of the literature just deals with the case where $f \colon \Omega_1 \to \mathbb D$ or $f \colon \mathbb D \to \Omega_1$, here one could consider a concatenation of maps but the problem is that $\gamma_2$ is not a Jordan domain.
Thanks in advance

$C\backslash\gamma_j$ is two domains. not one, for each $j$, so your notation is ambiguous. What map do you really consider? Each of those 4 maps has a homeomorphic extension to a map between the closures of the corresponding domains.

I don't consider the curves being closed, in fact I would like to consider simply curves. As an easy example take $\gamma_1 = [0,1]$ and $\gamma_2 = [300i,1000i]$ then the corresponding simply connected domains would be $\Omega_1 = \hat{\mathbb C} - \gamma_1$ and $\Omega_2 = \hat{\mathbb C} - \gamma_2$, which are both conformally equivalent to the unit disk and each other. Thus I can find a conformal map $\varphi \colon \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ and the question is whether or not it extends (at least) continuously.

You should explain more precisely what do you mean by "extension in terms of prime ends".
In the case that $\gamma_j$ are simple curves (images of $[0,1]$ under injective continuous maps), each point of such a curve, except $\gamma_j(0)$ and $\gamma_j(1)$ corresponds to two prime ends while each point $\gamma_j(0),\gamma_j(1)$
correspond to one prime end. The conformal map extends to a homeomorphism between the prime ends compactifications.
All this is easily obtained by considering branches $\phi_j$ of
$$\sqrt{\frac{z-\gamma_j(0)}{z-\gamma_j(1)}}, \quad j=1,2.$$
which map conformally your $D_j=\bar{\mathbf{C}}\backslash\gamma_j$ onto Jordan domains. Composing your $f$ with $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2^{-1}$ you reduce to the case of Jordan domains.
However your map usually does not extend to a continuous map of $\bar{\mathbf{C}}$ to itself.
If your curves are rectifiable, such a continuous extension is only possible when $f is a linear fractional transformation.

I am not sure that I understand 100% what is written. I guess what you are saying is that we have a homeomorphisms between the images of prime ends of $\gamma_1$ and the prime ends of $\gamma_2$. Also in the case when you compose $f$ with $\phi_1$ and $\phi^{-1}_2$ you still have a map between two Jordan domains, in that case can you link the used theorem or tell me where you found it? Do I understand you correctly that in the case where $f$ is not a linear fractional transformation one does not get a continuous extension from $\partial \Omega_1$ to $\partial \Omega_2$?


Yes. 2. Milnor's book "Dynamics in one complex variable" is the best source that I know, but many other books on conformal mapping explain this. 3. Yes, if the curves are rectifiable, but in general this is not true.


So just to be sure and to answer the original  question in the case when $\gamma_j$ are rectifiable curves: The map $f \colon \hat{\mathbb C} - \gamma_1 \to \hat{\mathbb C} - \gamma_2$ doesn't extend to a continuous map from the sphere to itself but extends to a homeomorphism between $P(\gamma_1)$ and $P(\gamma_2)$ where $P(\gamma_j)$ for $j \in {1,2}$ denotes the set of prime ends. Is it technically okay to say that $P(\gamma_j) \subseteq \gamma_j$ since technically prime ends are equivalent classes of crosscuts?

No, one cannot say that $P(\gamma)\subset\gamma$ is any sense, because there are TWO points of $P(\gamma)$ associated to each point of $\gamma$ (except two endpoints of $\gamma$). A cut in the plane has two "shores", as they explain in elementary textbooks.

Allright I understand this fact and the reasons that there are two points. Suppose that one knows that $f(\gamma_1(t^{+}) = f(\gamma_1(t^{-}))$ ( I guess one does not have a extension that is a homeomorphism) where $\pm$ denotes one of the shores. Then it is better to say that the image of both prime-ends correspond to a single prime end of $\gamma_2$ instead of saying they get identified to the same boundary point of $\gamma_2$? I am asking since I am interested in writing in saying that there exists some point on the boundary $\partial \Omega_1$ that gets mapped to $\partial \Omega_2$.

Let us say that two prime ends of $C\backslash\gamma$ are equivalent if they correspond to one point of $\gamma$. Suppose that $f$ has an extension to a homeomorphism $P(\gamma_1)\to P(\gamma_2)$. Then $f$ can be extended to the homeomorphism of the sphere if and only if this extension to prime ends sends equivalent points to equivalent points. For rectifiable $\gamma_j$, this can only happen when $f$ is linear-fractional.

Okay great thanks I believe I got it now! Thanks sooo much for the help :)
